# Trying to make sense of this TypeScript compiler error

Tags: typescript

I'm upgrading to MUI5 and this TS error came up. If I remove `backgroundFill` then the error goes away. I just don't know how to satisfy the compiler right now.

```
import React from "react";

import SvgIcon, { SvgIconProps } from "@mui/material/SvgIcon";

const MyIcon = ({
  backgroundFill,
  ...props
}: SvgIconProps & { backgroundFill: string }) => (
```

TS compiler message:

```
const MyIcon: ({ backgroundFill, ...props }: {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    classes?: Partial<SvgIconClasses> | undefined;
    color?: "inherit" | "action" | "disabled" | "primary" | "secondary" | ... 4 more ... | undefined;
    ... 5 more ...;
    viewBox?: string | undefined;
} & CommonProps & Omit<...> & {
    ...;
}) => JSX.Element
The inferred type of 'MyIcon' cannot be named without a reference to '@mui/material/node_modules/@mui/system'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to debug without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but it seems like you simply need a [return type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) for your component.

I suggest using `React.ReactElement` when you're rendering JSX or a component that ultimately renders JSX:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAGhLMoFEcUQUA7GAXzjSghDgBEUOjAEBuAFChIsRHADKANwDmASXIRWNGAE8wKBSvWaACrzBEuPPoIACILMAD0IDDBRRgGHOIkSNrATwALI6xqxwALxwABQIEnBwAEYUANbKvFisSABiwDg4VAlwAHRlYOYEEhwAXIZqAWYQFnAAZHIp5OmZ2XkFdUGerMpwHACUdaQUMIzMbPCRAHxwADxKDZpwTouSQA)

```ts
import {default as React, ReactElement} from "react";
import { SvgIcon, type SvgIconProps } from "@mui/material";

const MyIcon = ({
  backgroundFill,
  ...props
}: SvgIconProps & { backgroundFill: string }): ReactElement => <SvgIcon />;
```